# convert hard code nsstring to nsdate

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

say i have this nsstring * date =  @"13th May-2015"
i want to convert it to something like this @"13/05/2015"

currently i am trying to do it with nsdateformatter:

```
NSString * dateStr  = @"13th May-2015";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatOriginal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatOriginal setDateFormat:@"dd MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatOriginal dateFromString:dateStr]; 

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatConverted = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatConverted setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString * convertedDateString =  [dateFormatConverted stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"this should be 13/05/2015,  %@", convertedDateString);
```

so i expect the converted date string became to 13/05/2015.

but above code fail to do so....any help with code example would be helpful, thanks guys.

Comment: See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: But I don't think "13th May" is legal in any scheme.

Comment: I've tried with `NSDataDetector` but it seems that the "-" between "May" and "2015" cause a no-detection (worked if I replace it with a space character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString * dateStr  = @"13th May-2015";

NSArray *stringComponentArray = [dateStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

NSMutableArray *workingArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:stringComponentArray];

NSMutableString *dateString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[workingArray firstObject]];

[dateString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"st" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[dateString length])];
[dateString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"nd" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[dateString length])];
[dateString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"rd" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[dateString length])];
[dateString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"th" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,[dateString length])];

[workingArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:dateString];

dateStr = [workingArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];


NSDateFormatter *dateFormatOriginal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatOriginal setDateFormat:@"dd MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatOriginal dateFromString:dateStr];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatConverted = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatConverted setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString * convertedDateString =  [dateFormatConverted stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"this should be 13/05/2015,  %@", convertedDateString);
```

Since your date string doesn't match with any of the iOS `Date formatter` styles. Uou need to play with the strings.Please have a look into above solution.

Answer (score 0):

13th May-2014 is not "dd MM-yyyy" format.

You have to make sure your input string matches the format string *exactly*.

Comment: err, i m not quite sure what format is it for 13th may-2014....any suggestion?thx

Comment: @seph - If you can't find it in the doc I linked, you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Remember to remove 'st, 'nd', 'rd' as well as 'th' for all the ordinals. (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc). Also, watch out for doing a straight [NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString] on it since 'August' ends with 'st'